# Pointing 1and1 domain to an S3 bucket

Tags: redirect, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns

I've registered my domain about a month ago (It's a .com, so I need to wait 60 days before being allowed to transfer the domain, which I will do as I'm fed up with 1and1's service)

I created an Amazon S3 bucket with my domain name: example.com and www.example.com.

All my Amazon S3 settings are in order, I've enabled website hosting, I have an index document...

In 1and1, I've set my redirect destination for example.com to my S3 bucket endpoint.

When I hit save: "Operation Failed, The redirect URL is invalid."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *In 1and1, I've set my redirect destination for example.com to my S3 bucket endpoint.*  Let's clarify that.  Assuming the bucket is named "example.com" what S3 bucket endpoint did you exactly specify?  `http://example.com.s3-website-[region].amazonaws.com`?

Comment: yep. list the precise s3 bucket endpoint. including 'http' or not. (suggestion: in @Michael-sqlbot's example, the CNAME should be `example.com.s3-website-[region].amazonaws.com`, **not** starting with `http`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I tried both http://example.com.s3-website-[region].amazonaws.com, and http://www.example...

Comment: @tedder42 Hi, I just tried it with the http in front... It worked, but it just redirects me to the link that i put in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you configured your domain name to use a Redirect instead of a CNAME record. Create a CNAME record to your AWS domain.

Here are some instructions:

http://help.1and1.com/domains-c36931/manage-domains-c79822/dns-c37586/enter-a-cname-record-for-your-domain-a643600.html

Sometimes people don't want to create CNAMEs for their root domain and prefer to redirect from  example.com to www.example.com

Comment: CNAMEs at the root are a violation of the relevant RFCs.

Comment: You can't redirect an APEX domain (foo.com) with a CNAME.  So, you're options are: a) redirect a sub-domain, like www. instead; b) do a double redirect... first to the www.... at amazon and then Amazon's www.... bucket will redirect; c) Pay Amazon to use their Route 53 service which can do this or ..... d) sign up for a free CloudFlare account and get apex domain redirection and SSL (plus much else)

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to wait 60 days.

There are two different services that are commonly confused because providers often market then together: domain registrar services and domain hosting.

You can change your hosting provider at any time, by changing the configuration options with the current registrar. This change typically takes effect almost immediately, though conventional wisdom is that it may require up to 48 hours to take effect globally.

Create a new "hosted zone" in Route 53 for your domain.  Take note of the four "awsdns" name servers that Route 53 assigns.

Log in to your registrar's admin portal and find the option the change your authoritative name server configuration.   Replace the registrar's default name servers with the four provided by Route 53.

You will then use the Route 53 console to create your DNS records, including the appropriate "Alias" records pointing your domain to the S3 web site endpoint.

After the 60 days, you can change the registrar to Route 53, or any other registrar you like, continuing to use the authoritative name servers assigned to your domain by Route 53.

Route 53 is the simplest option for DNS hosting when you are using S3 for static website hosting (or CloudFront or Elastic Load Balancer) simply because of the tight integration provided by Alias records, which offer capabilities that CNAMEs can't and other DNS hosting providers can't, because they don't have direct access to the operational internals of AWS.